# How to start a task that takes a parameter and returns a value?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to launch a task in C# that both takes a parameter and returns a value, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Here's as close as I have gotten: here's a task that is expected to return an int. I'm my lambda, I'm also showing it taking a single parameter, o:

```
Task<int> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>((o) => { return 2 ; }, 3);
Console.WriteLine(task1.Result);  // prints 2
```

The above line works (it returns a hardcoded value of 2, but you can see it's doing nothing with the parameter o, making it useless. If I do something with the parameter o, like this:

```
Task<int> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>((o) => { return (2 * o) ; }, 3);
```

I get a syntax message that Delegate 'System.Func' does not take 1 arguments.

Any help on how to achieve both things (pass a parameter and retrieve a value) from a task would be great!

Answer (score 3):

The input ( state ) parameter for a `Task` can only be of type `object`, so it's actually not type safe.

The generic type parameter on `Task<T>` is the return type of the `Task`.

The best option is to use a closure:

```
int i = 3;
Task<int> task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew( () => 2 * i );
```

Answer (score 3):

`o` is the object state, and in your case, is the value you are passing in, or 3. You can cast it to an `int`.

```
Task<int> task = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(o => {
    return 2 * (int)o;
}, 3);

Console.WriteLine(task.Result); // prints 6
```

See msdn's documentation on [TaskFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory).[StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321394) which states:

> **state**
>
> Type: System.Object
>
> An object containing data to be used by the function delegate.

Comment: @svick I agree, I was just trying to fit my answer in with the OP's question.

Comment: is it just me or would it have made more sense to include the specification of the parameter type in the generic types of the signature, at least as additional overload(s)?

Comment: Closures have overhead compared to object states because it allocates extra delegates. Check Joe Hoag's post at Microsoft PfxTeam blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Theres `Task<t>` you can use (look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx))
T is the return value, of course. As of the parameter - you can just use ur variables within the annonymous delegate, so if you have the `int o` defined outside the task, you can just use it within the tasks annonymous delegate scope.
you can see a sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8127421/1394380)

Comment: So you're saying avoid specifying parameters to the lambda.. right?
In other words, instead of  (o) => ..do something with o, declare a temporary to hold o outside the task itself, and then just use () =>  ..do something with o

Comment: The `task<T>` class accepts a Func delegate, which either receives no params and returns T, or accepts and object and returns T. you probably can use the object overload, as described on msdn, but theres no reason to. Any annonymous / lambda delegate you're writing in .net also has access to the variables of the scope its define it, as you can see in the link i provided / Nicholas Butlers answer. Theres no need for you to specify params in lambda, yup.