# How to correctly get function return value from a task?

Tags: c#, wpf, task

I'm trying (with no success) to call a function asynchronously and wait for its return value

```
bool result = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { return StupidFunction(someParameter); }).Result;

if (result)
    MessageBox.Show("Yes");
else
    MessageBox.Show("No");
```

where stupid function is a `public static bool` function

and the application hangs forever.

Comment: So what does `StupidFunction()` do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10920174/how-to-start-a-task-that-takes-a-parameter-and-returns-a-value

Comment: Are you looking for `bool result = await Task.Factory...`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson it's an import function which return a true/false value

Comment: Well the code you posted would work unless `StupidFunction()` doesn't return, or if `StupidFunction()` does something with the UI.

Comment: it does not, it freezes the application hanging forever

Comment: Well then the function must not be returning. Try it with a simple implementation of `StupidFunction()` which just returns true or false immediately. It will not hang up.

Comment: You are not calling this function asynchronously, by the way. Merely starting a task does not make it async, by virtue of using `.Result` at the end, it makes it wait there until it gets the result. Why  not use the async/await pattern and mark `StupidFunction` async and await it?

Comment: I just want to make it run on a separate thread, so the ui is not blocked. but i need the result to make the messagebox to be modal

Comment: Thats not what the code you are posting is doing, its still blocking for the `.Result`, using a `Task` here is pointless. You need to add code to the task itself to update the UI, or do whatever with the result and then just let it run, once you wait for the result, you are blocking.

Comment: in the function i manage a progress bar and a label, showing the operation progress...

Comment: Then you should add your messagebox code into the task so that you can run asynchronously, or just use the async/await pattern.

Comment: yes, but i need the messagebox to be modal

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be modal if its opened inside the task?

Comment: because i tried to do it, the messagebox appear under the main window and is not blocking

Answer (score 0):

resolved with

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    if (StupidFunction(someParameter))
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "yes")));
    else
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => MessageBox.Show(Application.Current.MainWindow, "no")));
});
```

Comment: This will only work on a WPF application, its not clear from the OP that this is WPF or Winforms, but glad you got it resolved.